# Refactor ECMAScript 6 destructuring assignment (ES2015) to old version javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to refactor a code from ECMAScript 6 to classic javascript.
I have this code of destructuring assignment.

`var {innerHTML: value} = e.target;`

Please give the equivalent of it

Thank you.

Comment: `var value = e.target.innerHTML;` - also, it isn't a good question when you could just [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Check [this one](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=var%20%7BinnerHTML%3A%20value%7D%20%3D%20e.target%3B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to do something like this:

```
var value = e.target.innerHTML;
```

The destructuring isn't doing anything too clever, it is just assigning the value of the `innerHTML` property on `e.target` to a new variable `value`.

Edit: Just saw @Emissary's comment. Snap!